# Bool var dbgotAltered defined in an enclosing scope

Tags: java, scope, boolean

I am pretty new to Java but I am also pretty sure that what
I am trying to do here will not disturb any future or
past time-lines but Eclipse sure won't let me get past this.
And I truly don't understand why this is happening or how
to fix this?

Simply stated: I am calling a function/method that COULD
delete a record (IF the button is pressed). The calling
method just wants to know if the user deleted (Altered)
the database?
I have used Bools like this without any problems. I have
looked at lambda, final, etc but my expertise is not
quite there yet, but again, this is a pretty simple
task. Thank you!

```
static Boolean EditRecord(int listboxIndex) {

Boolean dbgotAltered = false;
.
.
JButton button1 = new JButton("Delete"); 
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     

dbData.remove(listboxIndex);
dbgotAltered = true;

//  Local variable dbgotAltered defined in an 
//  enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
//  Looking for a fix for dbgotAltered. The Calling
//  procedure/method really wants to know?              
}
});     
.
.
return dbgotAltered;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't lying. Any variable used in inner class or lambda scope must either be 'marked' final, or must be 'effectively' final (meaning, you could have marked it final).

And the reasons are on display in your snippet.

Your snippet cannot do what you want here.

Code is like a recipe for baking:

1. Mix flour and eggs.
2. knead well.
3. roll into pasta.

What you're doing here is a bit of a trick:

1. Mix flour and eggs.
2. send an email to your friend to come to your house and knead well.
3. Don't wait, just carry right on, and roll your raw egg and unkneaded flour straight into pasta. Your kitchen is a gigantic mess now.
4. your friend sees your mail a few hours later, shows up, and just goes ????? what happened here?

That action listener you are configuring? The code inside does not run **immediately**. It will run when the user gets around to pressing your button. Which could easily be 5 hours from now, you don't know. All that the line `addActionListener` does is associate the listener to the button. It does not wait around twiddling its thumbs for the user to actually do it - that call returns immediately. It just tells the button what to do **WHEN** the user presses the button.

So, then this code runs `return dbgotAltered;` and will obviously always return false - the user has not been able to press that button in the 1 nanosecond it took the system to execute that line of code.

So, there are two problems here:

1. you can't have non-effectively-final variables that you read or write from within lambdas/anonymous classes (and this ActionListener definition is an anonymous class). You can fix that by using a level indirection, such as via `AtomicBoolean`.
2. ... but you're confused on the timing here. The editRecord method *cannot* return whether the user pressed the button or not, you need completely different code for this. most likely, the act of pressing the button should cause some code to run.

Comment: Wow! Thank you RZ. I was not aware of Atomic Boolean; that got me back on track. Also I sure do appreciate your analogy; that was also very helpful. TY!